# Cannot install SUPERAL 9600 USB Ethernet Card KY-RS9600 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, drivers, usb-network-adapter

### Summary

I cannot use a SUPERAL 9600 USB Ethernet Card KY-RS9600 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, although there are drivers for it on Internet and in its driver CD.

### Beginning

I bought a JP108 USB Adapter for RJ45.

When I try to detect drivers for it, Windows detects as an unknown Network Adapter. Right clicking on it on device manager, it shows that USB\Vid_0fe6&Pid_8101&Rev_0101 ID.

It comes with a CD with drivers, according following folders:

```
E:\AX88772A\windows\Vista\AX88772_772A_760_Vista_32bit_Driver_v3.8.3.22_WHQL
E:\AX88772A\windows\Vista\AX88772_772A_760_Vista_64bit_Driver_v3.10.3.22_WHQL
E:\AX88772A\windows\WinXP\AX88772_772A_760_WinXP2K3_64bit_Driver_v3.6.3.35_WHQL
E:\AX88772A\windows\WinXP\AX887772A_WinXP2K_32bit_Driver_v3.4.3.35_WHQL
E:\AX88772A\windows\WinXP\AX88772_772A_760_WinXP2K3_64bit_Driver_v3.6.3.35_WHQL\AX88772_772A_760_WinXP2K3_64bit_Driver_v3.6.3.35_WHQL
E:\AX88772A\windows\WinXP\AX887772A_WinXP2K_32bit_Driver_v3.4.3.35_WHQL\AX88772_772A_760_WinXP2K_32bit_Driver_v3.4.3.35_WHQL
E:\AX88772A\windows\Windows 7\AX88772_772A_760_Win7_32bit_Driver_v3.12.3.2_WHQL
E:\AX88772A\windows\Windows 7\AX88772_772A_760_Win7_64bit_Driver_v3.14.3.2_WHQL
E:\JP1081 1082 9700Driver\WIN 7
E:\JP1081 1082 9700Driver\Windows 2k 2003
E:\JP1081 1082 9700Driver\Windows Vista
E:\JP1081 1082 9700Driver\Windows xp
E:\SR9600Driver\Vista
E:\SR9600Driver\win7
E:\SR9600Driver\Windows2000
E:\SR9600Driver\Windowsxp2003
```

But none of them functioned.

I installed it on Windows XP (not my machine) and it functioned.

### Internet

Searching for drivers on Internet, I discovered that:

1. It is one of that Chinese so cheap generic devices;
2. Manufacturer site on Internet does not exist;
3. It has more than one name, but someone posted a common name on Internet: SUPERAL 9600 USB Ethernet Card KY-RS9600 [HOW TO Archives](http://www.howtoarchives.com/2010/10/download-usb-to-lan-adapter-driver);
4. Manufacturer name is SUPERAL Semiconductor, Inc. on Windows XP driver description;
5. On other site I found ARCHEON Semiconductor, Inc. [http://nyekit.blogspot.com.br](http://nyekit.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/usbvid0fe6-sr9600-usb-to-fast-ethernet.html);
6. Some solutions were on Mediafire and Megaupload sites, but you know what happens to these services...

I downloaded some other drivers on Internet:
[2xdizzy.blogspot.com.br](http://2xdizzy.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/ky-rs9600.html)
[forum.clubedohardware.com.br](http://forum.clubedohardware.com.br/adaptador-rede-usb/588445?s=7bc9fb842139fca8e24940d696433757&p=4837062)
[www.drvsky.com](http://www.drvsky.com/driver/SR9600.htm)
...

But they does not solve my problem for Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit...

### Help

Does someone have any help for me?

Is is possible to connects to Internet inside a VirtualBox virtual machine with Windows XP image and with that device filtered for it? Also, it is possible to share the Internet from the virtual machine to the real one (my)?

Is it possible to change the driver files to match my device on my OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution for this adapter. A man has to buy another adapter to use in x64 or to use a x86 Windows SO...

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a Davicom DM9601 based adapter. At least the Linux driver dm9601 lists the vendor and device id you mentioned in the source: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob_plain;f=drivers/net/usb/dm9601.c;hb=HEAD

Since this chip seems to be rather old (according to the kernel source USB 1.1, so no Hi-Speed mode), I doubt there is any Windows driver for x64 systems. At least Davicom itself does not offer x64 drivers while they have x86 drivers: http://www.davicom.com.tw/page1.aspx?no=209814 - So just hacking inf (as it often helps, if just vendor or device ids do not match) will not help.

"Connecting" the adapter to a virtual machine running Windows XP in VirtualBox should work but might have some quirks. In my experience passing control to USB devices on the host is not absolutely reliable.

Allowing internet access to to host system will work if you set up the virtual machine to use host-only or bridged networking (not the default NAT) and enable the Internet Connection Sharing feature of Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126

But I would rather recommend to use a supported network adapter or at least use a tiny linux system like IPCop in VirtualBox instead of abusing Windows XP for your needs.

Comment: I'm not that experienced Linux user, so please, how to share ethernet connection on, for example, a Slackware distro?

Comment: I don't have Slackware specific instructions but basically you need to turn on IP forwarding in the kernel and add iptables rules to enable NAT. Another way would be to bridge both NICs using brctl. Just answering the questions in the install wizard from IPCop would be easier though. Or get a NIC that works on a x64 edition of Windows. Is there any specific reason to use a USB based NIC? Reliable PCI NICs which are supported out of the box on popular operating systems cost just some bucks.

Comment: No. Only the RJ45 input from my computer broke one of its contacts (there are now 7 contacts instead of 8). Then I bought the cheaper USB to RJ45 adapter I found on Internet :) According to store, that product would support Windows 7 and I believed on that. So here I am :)

Comment: To change RJ45 input from my computer a technician wanted me to pay R$ 150,00 (about US$ 75,00) while that adapter cost only R$ 10,00 (about US$ 5,00) to me XD

Comment: Windows 7 is indeed supported but only in the 32 bit edition. I assume you are using a laptop, since in a desktop computer a PCI adapter would be a better solution. I also assume the missing pin inside the jack broke networking also (50% chance, since only 4 of the 8 pins are needed for fast ethernet). So I suggest to a) have the adapter swapped at the store with one working on 64 bit Windows editions. b) use wireless networking (which is probably already there since it is a laptop). or c) live with the workaround running e.g. IPCop in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

so I was in the same boat and finally managed to find a way to make the damn USB adapter work :) 
I downloaded and installed the Davicom drivers for Win 7 that Gurken Papst mentioned. I know they're not supposed to be the exact thing, but apparently the adapter didn't mind much. Had to manually assign them in the device manager, but other than that it was smooth sailing. Thought I'd share, since so many people seem to be having trouble with this.

Comment: Excellent! Share it, please!